# Visual Studio Code - Code Runner : 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

I have installed Visual Studio Code (VSC) and [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner).
When I use the terminal to execute my code it works fine and I get the results in the terminal window:

[image]

However, when I try to use Code Runner's keyboard shortcut `Ctrl+Alt+N`I keep getting this error message:
[image]

Which baffles me because VSC shows this:
[image]

I've tried rebooting (solution on another related SO question), creating a new conda environment inside VSC along with what seemed to be relevant from the VSC documentation [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_manually-specify-an-interpreter) and [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial).

If anyone can help me understand what I need to be doing differently I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set a symbolic link between calling Python3 and Python since they're effectively the same thing.  If you go into a normal command prompt / terminal and type Python3, you may get the same error. Whereas, if you type Python, it will launch the Python interpreter.

**Close VSCode**

If you're a Windows user you can use [mklink](https://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html) to sort it out — open a Command Prompt as an Administrator, then navigate to your Python installation.  e.g.:

```
cd C:\Python38
mklink python3.exe python.exe
```

In Linux, you can set a [Symbolic link](https://kb.iu.edu/d/abbe):

```
cd /usr/bin/python3
ln -s python.exe python3.exe
```

Startup VSCode again and it should work.